# Using LangChainJS to connect to Weaviate in Docker, why is the connection refused?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, langchain, weaviate, langchain-js

I'm trying to use Weaviate as a vector store in an app I'm putting together, I'm running both Weaviate and my NodeJs server in containers on a default Docker Compose network.  They are connecting but Weaviate seems to be refusing the connections and I cannot figure out why?
My Docker Compose configuration is the following:

```
weaviate:
        image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.21.3
        environment:
            OPENAI_APIKEY: xxx
            QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
            AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'false'
            PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
            DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-openai'
            ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-openai'
            CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ENABLED: 'true'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ALLOWED_KEYS: 'xxx'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_USERS: 'my_app'
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - ./docker/weaviate/vectors:/var/lib/weaviate
        command:
            - --port
            - '8080'
            - --scheme
            - http
```

In my application I am creating the Weaviate client and connecting as follows:

```
const client = weaviate.client({
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'weaviate:8080',
  apiKey: new weaviate.ApiKey('xxx')
});

await WeaviateStore.fromTexts(
  texts,
  metadata,
  new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
  {
    client,
    indexName: 'foo',
    textKey: 'text',
    metadataKeys: ['source']
  }
);
}
```

However, when WeaviateStore.fromTexts() gets called I see the following error:

```
Error: 'Error adding vectors' FetchError: request to http://weaviate:8080/v1/batch/objects failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.48.3:8080
```

From this it seems that the request is locating the server but it is rejected. I also tried this without the API Key and setting `AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED` to `true`, but I got the same error message. Any advice on what I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Duda from Weaviate here!

Your command statement is missing the host to bind for, so it's probably not listening to anything.

here is a working example:

```
services:
    weaviate:
        image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.21.3
        environment:
            OPENAI_APIKEY: xxx
            QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
            AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'false'
            PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
            DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-openai'
            ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-openai'
            CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ENABLED: 'true'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_ALLOWED_KEYS: 'xxx'
            AUTHENTICATION_APIKEY_USERS: 'my_app'
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - ./docker/weaviate/vectors:/var/lib/weaviate
        command:
            - --host
            - 0.0.0.0
            - --port
            - '8080'
            - --scheme
            - http
```

You can use our [Docker Compose Configurator](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/installation/docker-compose#configurator) when you want to craft a customized docker-compose :)

Thanks for using Weaviate!

Comment: Hi, I got thing working by using weaviate:latest. Looking at the docker images both 1.21.3 and latest have the final line `CMD ["--host" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8080" "--scheme" "http"]` as a result I dropped the `command:` section entirely.